# How to solve ambiguous declarations elegantly in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, variable-declaration, function-declaration

```
struct A
{
    A(int) {}
    A(std::initializer_list<int>) {}
};

template<typename T>
struct B
{
    B(A) {}
    B(std::initializer_list<T>) {}
};

int main()
{
    int n{};
    B   m1(A{n}); // error: call A::A(std::initializer_list<int>)
    B   m2(A(n)); // error: just a function declaration: B m2(A n);
}
```

As shown in the code above, I want to call `B::B(A(int))` to construct an object of class `B`. I have two choices:

1. `B m1(A{n});`
2. `B m2(A(n));`

According to [C++ Core Guidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es23-prefer-the--initializer-syntax), the former is preferred.

However, `B m1(A{n});` will call `A::A(std::initializer_list<int>)` rather than `A::A(int)`, which is not intended. So, I have to use `B m2(A(n));`, but it is just a function declaration: `B m2(A n);`!

**How to solve ambiguous declarations elegantly in C++11?**

Comment: `B m2{A(n)};` will call `B::B(std::initializer_list<T>)`, is it what you want?

Comment: No, that is not I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [almost always auto](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) idiom to the rescue.

I'm not sure what you intended T to be, since it is unclear in the code example.  I used `double` because... why not.

```
int main() {
    auto n = int{};
    auto m1 = B<double>(A{n});
    auto m2 = B<double>(A(n));
}
```

Disclaimer:  about half the C++ developers I talk to in real life (at my job) absolutely despise *almost always auto*.  I like it (but I've done a lot of C# with `var`, F#, and TypeScript, where that's business as usual; and C++ template code and lambda-with-auto), but there are **many** who are ardently anti auto.  If you decide to use *almost always auto* in your own project, I strongly urge you to discuss with your co-workers and get team consensus before going down that path.

Answer (score 3):

You can add another parentheses for the argument `A(n)`.

```
B m2((A(n)));
```

Comment: How ugly it is!

Answer (score 2):

How about...

```
auto m1 = B(A(n));
```